# How do I trigger a click event on an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to trigger a click event on an image

**Html**

```
<img src="https://www.bux.com/imagens/estrela_16.gif" border="0" height="16" width="16">
```

How do I get the image to fire an event with javascript?

Comment: No element having an `href` attribute appears at Question? What is expected result?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post a complete example with expected behaviour and actual behaviour

Comment: Clarified, grammar, added javascript in question since OP used javascript tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the jQuery selector to achieve that, like this:

```
$("img[src*='estrela_16.gif']").on('click', function() {
 // Do something...
});
```

In case you want to trigger the click event, do this:

```
$("img[src*='estrela_16.gif']").trigger('click');
```

or more direct:

```
$("img[src*='estrela_16.gif']").click();
```

More information can be found here https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/, and here http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: hey also help me to trigger click on this string Click the red dot

Comment: Well, you can wrap that string in a, say DIV as <div id="string">Click the red dot</div> then do this $('#string').click();

Answer (score 0):

```
something done...
$('img[src$="estrela_16.gif"]').click()
```